# I can't find drivers for a Lenovo b575e for Ubuntu

Tags: drivers

My laptop is a Lenovo b575e.

I wanted to set up Ubuntu on it, so I went to the Lenovo website to see if there are drivers for the Linux OS, but I found that the drivers are just for "RedHat and SUSE".

What to do to set up Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

That is not how Linux works. Linux supplies its own drivers during the installation of the operating system. Only your graphics card and maybe your NIC might benefit or could need a specific driver. But those are exceptions.

Install our Live Session onto a DVD or USB, boot from it (either by setting up your BIOS to boot from it or pick the "override boot with {dvd/usb}" method if that is applicable.

Let it start. Check with "try Ubuntu" it things work and then install the system.

You might need to do some preparation upfront: if you need a dual boot you need to make some unallocated space on your disks of at least a 30Gb so you can install an operating system onto that.